# How to calculate average and most frequent values per group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df`:

```
df =
   year  intensity  category
   2015  22         1
   2015  21         1
   2015  23         2
   2016  25         2
   2017  20         1
   2017  21         1
   2017  20         3
```

I need to group by `year` and calculate an average `intensity` and a most frequent `category`(per year).

I know that it's possible to calculate most frequent category as follows:

```
df.groupby('year')['category'].agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
```

I also know how to calculate average `intensity`:

```
df = df.groupby(["year"]).agg({'intensity':'mean'}).reset_index()
```

But I don't know how to put everything together without `join` operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `agg` with a dictionary to define how to aggregate each column.

```
df.groupby('year', as_index=False)[['category', 'intensity']]\
  .agg({'category': lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0], 'intensity':'mean'})
```

Output:

```
   year  category  intensity
0  2015         1  22.000000
1  2016         2  25.000000
2  2017         1  20.333333
```

Or you can still use lambda funcion

```
df.groupby('year', as_index=False)[['category','intensity']]\
  .agg({'category': lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0],'intensity':'mean'})
```

Comment: mode still need slice protection , since sometime it will return two value with same freq

Comment: I get error `ValueError: function does not reduce` in my real data set.

Comment: I think @W-B just pointed out, that we still might need to slice using pd.Series.mode, try the lambda version.

Comment: `lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0]`

Comment: @scala or try the second statement below the or.

Comment: But how do I put it into `agg`?

Comment: replace `pd.Series.mode` with `lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0]`

Comment: It worked. Please update your answer accordingly, Thanks.